# Geometric calculation: two kneading discs

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, geometric-construction

I have two kneading discs of a screw overlapping with each other at 60 deg. I know the cross section area of one disc and I want to know what will be the overlap area if the other disc is rotated at 60 deg, or 30 deg. I want to calculate the effect of change in stagger angle between two discs on the free space from one disc.! [Front view of two kneading discs at 60 deg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJTBL.png)

Comment: The tag "algebraic geometry" is wrong.

Comment: Do you know the exact geometry of 1 of the discs? or only the area? If you know the function describing the long edge of the discs then it shouldn't be too hard to come up with an answer

Comment: Hi @michielm, Thanks. Find the image with function for the radius of the flank in the attached image: [geometry of the kneading disc in twin-screw system](http://imgur.com/hH40Tld). Can you please tell me how to proceed from here to get answer to my original question.